# Command-line/NCurses based tool for browsing JDBC database

Tags: linux, database, command-line-interface, jdbc

I need to manipulate a database from Linux command-line. I already have [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) drivers for the database (specifically [DerbyDB](http://db.apache.org/derby/)). Now I need some sort of command-line or NCurses based tool for Linux.

I just need to issue some basic and simple INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements, nothing fancy. Are there any such tools? All the better if the tools are already packaged for Fedora.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good [reference](http://java-source.net/open-source/sql-clients) to various sql utilities.

Of these I've only used [sqlshell](http://bmc.github.com/sqlshell/) and it did what you e.g. sql from the command line. It's java based so you will need a java 6 jre to use it. The jar file version has a gui for installation so you might want the zip version.

Henplus also looks like it would do what you want.

I've not seen any of them in the repos.